# Нужно из static метода вызвать не static метод

Tags: java, android, static

Есть статический метод:

```
public static void mCount(String str){

    }
```

Нужно из него вызвать не статический метод и передать аргумент str:

```
public void setCredits(String str) {
        txtView.setText(str);
    }
```

Как это проще реализовать?

Comment: `new <имя_класса>().setCredits(...)` - создать инстанс нужного класса и вызвать метод

Comment: не совсем понял, методы находятся в разных классах

Comment: в каком классе находится метод, который нужно вызвать?

Comment: метод который нужно вызвать в MainActivity

Comment: тогда, вроде как, нужно через контекст получить инстанс активити и вызвать метод

Comment: использую паттерн MVP контекст не хотелось бы никуда передавать и плодить кучу объектов тоже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передайте объект (у которого нужно вызвать нестатический метод) в ваш статический метод и вызывайте у него всё, что нужно:

```
public static void mCount(SomeObject someObject, String str) {
    someObject.setCredits(str);
}
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но по логике приложения мне не подходит. Но в дальнейшем буду использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему создав объект вызываемого класса и сделав его статичным.
Возможно это костыль но всё работает)

Comment: Вы `Activity` сохранили в статическую переменную?